# How to use a variable format string in string interpolation in C#

Tags: c#

I have following code:

```
var d = 1.25M;
var val = $"{d:#,#.#;(#,#.#);0}";
```

I would like to vary the formatter e.g. for 2 decimal places: `#,#.##;(#,#.##);0` so that it can be passed as a method argument.
How would I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

String interpolation (`$""`) is just [syntax sugar](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgZgpghgLgrgJwgZwLQBsD2BjK7VhwB22MAlpkarDAmcHDCgD4ACATAIwCwAUKwGYABByEBhIQG8+Q2SOGsALEICyACgCUUmXN0A3KAiEATIQF4hnAHTsArCoDcO3bINGD6c0IAkAIknGIADEADRBVkEOaqHhQRoOAAwAvr5OvLpJfElAA) for the `string.Format` method. You can use that directly.

```
var val2 = string.Format("{0:#,#.#;(#,#.#)}", d);
Console.WriteLine(val2); // "1.3", same as your original code
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't specify the format dynamically with string interpolation - you have to call `string.Format`

```
var format = "#,#.##;(#,#.##);0";
var val = string.Format("{0:" + format + "}", d);
```

You *could* use string interpolation to define the format, but then you have to "escape" the brackets within the format string:

```
var format = "#,#.##;(#,#.##);0";
var val = string.Format($"{{0:{format}}}", d);
```

Personally I would prefer the string concatenation so I don't have to think about the escaping as much (and there's no functional benefit).